# how to remove same points from different point patterns

Tags: spatstat

I have two observed point patterns on a network: `obs1` and `obs2`. These points are observed and noted into field measurement book. Some points among these (say `s`) are always found at the same location. That is `s` is common to both `obs1` and `obs2`. I want to exclude this set `s` from the point pattern before I calculate the intensity or any other process.

Is there a way(command/function) to compare two point processes and remove the common points between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing I can think of right now is to compute nearest neighbours
across the two patterns like below.

Artificial dataset where points 2 and 3 of X correspond to points 1 and
2 of Y:

```r
library(spatstat)
X <- unmark(chicago)[1:3]
Y <- unmark(chicago)[2:5]
plot(X, chars = 24, cols = "blue")
plot(Y, cex = 1.5, cols = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Cross distances:

```r
d <- nncross(X, Y, what = c("dist", "which"))
```

Id in X of points with very close neighbour in Y:

```r
whichX <- which(d$dist <= .Machine$double.eps)
```

Corresponding points in Y:

```r
whichY <- d$which[whichX]
```

Resulting plot:

```r
Xnew <- X[-whichX]
Ynew <- Y[-whichY]
plot(Xnew, chars = 24, cols = "blue")
plot(Ynew, cex = 1.5, cols = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]